# How can I verify IAP purchases on my RESTAPI with googles server?

Tags: java, php, android

After the `public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase info)`is called, how can I verify the IAP purchase with google servers using PHP?

I need to verify receipts for the purposes of:

- Preventing IAP crackers
- Make it impossible to give digital content without a valid receipt.

Most of the questions like this that were asked have either outdated methods or where not answered at all. What is a good tutorial or way I can achieve this?

Comment: Please post your code.